# What's the fish shell equivalent to `set -o vi` to get vi/vim key bindings to access command history and edit?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, fish, homebrew

I'm one of the *"cursed ones"* that got their start in `vi` instead of `emacs` so the shell editing commands I am used to are set in bash with `set -o vi` but this doesn't work in the fish shell.

How can I enable `vi` / `vim` style key commands in the friendly interactive shell that runs when you install `fish` from https://brew.sh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a command in `fish` to enable this one time and that command is:

```
fish_vi_key_bindings
```

To set this at every start up for all instances of the shell, create a startup file if it doesn't exist (or touch the date in case it exists) and then add that command to the startup file.

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/fish 
touch ~/.config/fish/config.fish
echo fish_vi_key_bindings >> ~/.config/fish/config.fish
```

This is well documented on Stack Overflow as well, but I figured a clear answer here would help some people find the setup sooner. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444740/how-to-use-vi-mode-in-fish-shell